# How to change the default TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, default, isolation-level

I know the default TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in SQL Server is "read committed".  If I want to change it to "READ UNCOMMITTED", how may i make this configuration change?

note: I cannot use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL, which only apply in the current session.  I cannot add NOLOCK in the queries because there are thousands of queries involved.

Thanks

---

Thanks for your answer.  We are ok with reading dirty rows.  Update is not a problem in our case as well.  but, I really want to change this default config of isolation level.  Please kindly help.

I cannot "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED".  I must make the global change.

---

We have carefully reviewed both snapshot isolation level.  They cannot be used in our situation.

Comment: I am very curious as to what specific problem you are running into where read uncommitted is though to be your only solution? I am assuming some kind of lock contention, but there are many ways to resolve such problems.

Comment: I came across this looking to know if it is possible, because I am wondering if somebody may have done this to us. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4):

I really do not think you should set that at a global level. You should be setting this pretty carefully because you can end up with a lot of different problems:

- Lost Updates
- Non repeatable reads
- Dirty reads
- Phantom reads

There is no way to set this at a database or a server level - it can only be set at a connection level.

The best you can do at a database level is to set the `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` or `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` properties. Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[What about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216(SQL.80).aspx):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

It will only apply to the current transaction.

Comment: That will apply to not only the current transaction, but the duration of the connection.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763(v=SQL.90).aspx for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For **SQL Server**, you can only set **transaction isolation level** on **session(connection) level** but not on **global level** different from **MySQL**. So, every time you log out **SQL Server**, **transaction isolation level** is reset to `READ COMMITTED` which is **default transaction isolation level**.